# Zend Route - Remove parameter name from URL

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

I'm starting developing using Zend Framework and I have a question about routes. Is there a way to instead of having a URL like this:

www.mysite.com/newsletter/groups/edit/id/1

Have this:

www.mysite.com/newsletter/groups/edit/1

(without the parameter name **id**)

I already put this code to declare a custom route in my BootStrap file:

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();    

    /* Edit Groups */
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('groups/edit/:group_id',array('controller' => 'groups','action' => 'edit')); 
    $router->addRoute('group_edit', $route);

    return $router;
}
```

Then in my view file I use this to echo the URL:

```
<a href="<?=$this->url(array('group_id' => $group->getId()), 'group_edit');?>" class=""><?=$group->getName()?></a>
```

And the url is echoing the way I want:

```
<a href="/fuhrmann/newsletter/groups/edit/1" class="">Group 1</a>
```

This is my application.ini:

```
    [production]

appnamespace = "Application"

; Debug output
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

;PHP Setings
phpsettings.date.timezone = "America/Sao_Paulo"

; Include path
includePaths.models = APPLICATION_PATH "/models"
includePaths.application = APPLICATION_PATH
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

; Bootstrap
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"


; Front Controller
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.env = APPLICATION_ENV
resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.Action_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "actions"
;resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
;resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/newsletter"
;resources.frontController.returnresponse = 1

; Layout
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"


; Views
resources.view.helperPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views"
resources.view.scriptPath.Default  = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/scripts"
resources.view.doctype = "HTML5"
resources.view.contentType = "text/html;charset=utf-8"
resources.view.helperPathPrefix = "Views_Helpers_"
resources.view.filterPathPrefix = "Views_Filters_"

resources.db.adapter = "PDO_SQLITE"


[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1


[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = true

resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.dbname = "newsletter"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.db.params.charset = utf8
```

My complete Boostrap file:

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initDoctype()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    }

    /**
     * Init Autoloader
     */
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
    }

    /**
     * Adiciona alguns routers
     */
    protected function _initRoutes()
    {

        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();


        /* Edit Groups*/
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/groups/edit/:groupId',array('controller' => 'group','action' => 'edit')); 
        $router->addRoute('group_edit', $route);


        return $router;
    }

}
```

My index.php (inside public) file:

```
<?php
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

The problem is, when I click to open this page (the edit group page) I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Router_Exception' with message 'group_id is not specified' in C:\xampp\htdocs\fuhrmann\newsletter\library\Zend\Controller\Router\Route.php:354 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fuhrmann\newsletter\library\Zend\Controller\Router\Rewrite.php(470): Zend_Controller_Router_Route->assemble(Array, true, true) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\fuhrmann\newsletter\library\Zend\View\Helper\Url.php(49): Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite->assemble(Array, NULL, true, true) #2 [internal function]: Zend_View_Helper_Url->url(Array, NULL, true) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\fuhrmann\newsletter\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(350): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\fuhrmann\newsletter\application\layouts\scripts\layout.phtml(22): Zend_View_Abstract->__call('url', Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\fuhrmann\newsletter\application\layouts\scripts\layout.phtml(22): Zend_View->url(Array, NULL, true) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\fuhrmann\newsletter\library\Zend\View.php(108): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\fu in C:\xampp\htdocs\fuhrmann\newsletter\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 336
```

Inside my EDIT action I can do a var_dump in all request params to see if the groupId is set, and yes, it is!

```
array(3) { ["groupId"]=> string(3) "555" ["controller"]=> string(6) "groups" ["action"]=> string(6) "edit" }
```

I already have searched for a lot of answers here and by the way, [I found a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298386/need-help-in-zend-framework-url-rewrite) with an answer but no solution for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your solutions as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, **solved**!

What I did was to add a default value (NULL) to the group_id, so in my Bootstrap file I have this now:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/groups/edit/:group_id',array('controller' => 'groups','action' => 'edit', 'group_id' => NULL));
```

Thanks @philien!

Answer (score 0):

You can try by removing the underscore :

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();    

    /* Edit Groups */
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('groups/edit/:groupId',array('controller' => 'groups','action' => 'edit')); 
    $router->addRoute('group_edit', $route);

    return $router;
}
```

And after :

```
<a href="<?=$this->url(array('groupId' => $group->getId()), 'group_edit');?>" class=""><?=$group->getName()?></a>
```

Underscore are bad to use in this case, I choose to put names in CamelCased.

Comment: I've tried to change what you said, but still getting the error. Maybe something in my boostrap file...I've edited my answer with the complete code of the bootstrap file. If I point to **http://localhost/newsletter/groups/edit/groupId/1** all works.